# Teradata syntax: unicode delimited identifier

Tags: teradata

I am getting error while trying to run the query in Teradata 13.0 How to write this query? I converted this oracle query to Teradata query:

```
select sb.name,
       sb.address1, 
       sb.address2, 
       sb.city, 
       sb.stateprovince,
       sb.postalcode, 
       sb.country, 
       sb.cid, 
       sb.item, 
       sb.mcnum, 
       sb.dmh, 
       sb.hy, 
       sb.firstname, 
       sb.lastname, 
       sb.email, 
       sb.monikerexec, 
       sb.res,
 (select cid from (select * from abc.submissions where res is not null order by res asc) where name = sb.name and item <> sb.item and res < sb.res and rownum =1) as mins,
  (select min(price) from ap.hist where name = sb.name) as minauc,
       sb.cat, 
       sb.uni
 from abc.submission sb
order by sb.item
```

Error:[image]

Comment: You need an alias for that derived table `(select cid from (select * from abc.submissions where res is not null order by res asc) AS ALIASNAME where name = sb.name and item <> sb.item and res < sb.res and rownum =1) as mins`

Comment: @JNevill If i do that it gives error for order by cannot be used in subquery error and i need order by as there is  rownum =1 condition in there.

Comment: You can't order by in a subquery regardless of whether or not you provide an alias. By not providing an alias you go from having one problem, to two. I suspect a windowing function would be better here. I'll see if I can whip something up if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem isn't so much the lack of an Alias (which is a problem), but rather the need for an `ORDER BY` in a subquery so that the appropriate `cid` can be picked out in the first subquery `minauc` in the `SELECT` statement.

Instead of doing an `ORDER BY` and trying to grab the first record, you could use `QUALIFY`, which uses Windowing functions to pick the record you want:

```
SELECT 
    sb.NAME, 
    sb.address1, 
    sb.address2, 
    sb.city, 
    sb.stateprovince, 
    sb.postalcode,
    sb.country, 
    sb.cid, 
    sb.item, 
    sb.mcnum, 
    sb.dmh, 
    sb.hy, 
    sb.firstname, 
    sb.lastname, 
    sb.email, 
    sb.monikerexec, 
    sb.res,
    sb2.cid AS mins, 
    (
        SELECT min(price)
        FROM ap.hist
        WHERE NAME = sb.NAME
    ) AS minauc, 
    sb.cat, 
    sb.uni
FROM abc.submission sb
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc.Submission sb2 ON
    sb.name = sb2.name AND
    sb.item <> sb.item AND
    sb2.res < sb.res AND
    sb2.res IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sb.name ORDER BY res asc) = 1
```

This uses a JOIN to bring the records together, then, using the `QUALIFY` only allows through the joined record that has the lowest `res`.

Comment: both are not working : errors: ordered analytical functions are not allowed in subqueries        and    top n option is not supported in subquery

Comment: I just made a pretty big edit by switching the query to use a JOIN. Then sticking the QUALIFY on the main query so Teradata wouldn't balk. I believe this is functionally equivalent to what you were attempting above.

Comment: Thanks @jnevill this worked.. but if i want to expand this query say there is one more statement added to it same as the other one but different table then how to use qualify ?   select custid from (select * from ap.ahist where bid is not null order by bid desc) where name = sb.name and rownum =1) as custid

Comment: You could use the same logic to Join that table in (`ON sb.name = ap.name AND ap.bid IS NOT NULL`) and then your Qualify would need to ORDER BY in a more complex way. `ORDER BY bid DESC, res ASC` That should work, but you might have to monkey with it a bit. When in doubt, take the QUALIFY off, focus on a specific `sb.name` and figure out which record of the many records you would want, and shape your `QUALIFY` to match. There may be other ways to do this too, so if your query keeps growing and you start to see some nasty cartesian joins happening, then you'll have to experiment more,.